# Domino server 9.0.1FP10 IF5 not starting after updating from Domino 8.5.2FP4 and changing OS from Win2003-32b to 2012 64bits

Tags: ibm-domino

I update de Domino 8.5.2 32bits on a Windows 2003 32 bits to a Domino 9.0.1 FP10 IF5 64 bits on a Windows 2012 R2 64bits.

The Domino server do not start when using the shortcut. Allow to choose to start as a service or an application and just stop after that.

Console.log is empty (only date of last execution).

What to check next ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third party product was the problem.
Blocking process.
Kill the running aplication, and restart (start manual in windows).
Then Domino server start smoothly.